# How can I emulate Windows Server 2008 R2 with QEMU? / Cannot virtualize Win2K8 R2 using QEMU on Windows Host

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, qemu

I have used precompiled QEMU 2.2.0 (64-bit version) to emulate a PC running Windows Server 2008 R2.
The Host OS is Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit, and my CPU doesn't support Intel VT-x so I can't use any other virtualization software(e.g. VirtualBox, VMWare Player, Hyper-V,...).

I tried normal configuration and a VirtIO configuration for guest but none of them worked for me.
This is the BSoD I get when I start the guest:

```
***STOP: 0x0000005D (0x00000000078BFBF9, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000)
```

To reproduce this error, I used this command:

```
C:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -boot d -drive file=WIN2k8R2.qcow2,if=virtio -cdrom WIN2k8r2.iso
```

Precompiled binaries are available at http://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/

Comment: Do not use QEMU for this. It is overkill. Use VirtualBox (which is free) to run your Windows server. Windows is quite buggy on QEMU. You can check the stop code on the Microsoft website. You can go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and look for the error code. The error code can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559072(v=vs.85).aspx . According to that page, the emulated CPU isn't supported by Windows.

Comment: My research indicates that this is caused by a known bug in QEMU's x64 CPU emulation. I've suffered the same issue trying to run Server 2008 on QEMU x64 hosted by Windows 7. (Like the original poster, I must use QEMU -- in my case I need an emulator that can run without admin rights.)